# Remapping Wolf King TimberWolf keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys

Question: How do you remap the top 8 internet hotkeys on a Wolf King TimberWolf?

---

Info: In case you haven't figured it out yet, I have a [TimberWolf](http://www.wolfkingusa.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=10&Itemid=10) keyboard. It has 8 built in hotkeys for various browser function. I hardly ever use these keys and was wondering if I might be able to re-map them to actually useful things.

~N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Qliner HotKeys](http://www.qliner.com/hotkeys/)? (Freeware)

Comment: It's crashing on windows 7, but it's probably the answer. thanks.